# This question was on my physics test (about basic DC circuits)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, short-circuits

So in the following question:
[image: Image shows DC Circuit with resistor followed by another resistor that is shorted and then another resistor in series, all with resistance of 100 Ohms]

Because the wire has a resistance of near 0, is there no current going through the resistor with the arrow pointing at it.

I understand that normally both resistors in parallel have some current, but does that apply in a circuit like this?

Comment: Yes, in the real world the wire has "some" resistance, not exactly zero, and there will be "some" current through the marked resistor. Assume the resistance of the wire is say 0.001 ohms, and find the current through (a) the wire, (b) the marked resistor. The answer to (b) should be near enough "zero" for most practical purposes!

Comment: @alephzero you should write that as an answer.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please take a minute to read our [guidelines for homework and exercise questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714) as well as [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093). We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and we prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Comment: Since the problem does not state what the resistance of the wire across the marked resistor is, you can only assume ideal wires (zero resistance) and therefore the wire is a short circuit and no current flows through the marked resistor. I offer this as an answer below and hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I understand that normally both resistors in parallel have some
>   current, but does that apply in a circuit like this?

In fact, you *can* apply [*current division*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_divider) to this problem.

First, recall that for two parallel connected resistors, the current $I$ divides as:

$$I_1 = I\frac{R_2}{R_1 + R_2}$$

$$I_2 = I\frac{R_1}{R_1 + R_2}$$

For the 'degenerate' case that, e.g., $R_1 = 0$, we have

$$I_1 = I\frac{R_2}{0 + R_2} = I$$

$$I_2 = I\frac{0}{0 + R_2} = 0$$

and so, as should be expected, *all* of the current is through the (ideal) wire in parallel with the resistor.

But there's actually, I believe, a more elegant way to reason about this.

(1) The voltage across an ideal wire is, by definition, *zero* for any value of current through.

(2) The voltage across two parallel connected circuit elements is *identical*

Thus, the voltage across a resistor in parallel with an ideal wire is *zero*.  By Ohm's law, the current through a (non-zero) resistance with zero voltage across is *zero*.

In other words, by Ohm's law and the definition of the parallel connected circuit elements, there is zero current through the resistor in parallel with a wire.

Clearly, for physical wires (with small but non-zero resistance), there is some (typically) *insignificant* current through the parallel connected resistor.

---

> Because the wire has a resistance of near 0, is there no current going
>   through the resistor with the arrow pointing at it.

This is, of course, *incorrect* (unless "no current" is not meant to be *no current*).  If the wire has non-zero (even if "near 0") resistance, then there is *some* (even if *insignificant*) current through the resistor with the arrow pointing at it and not *no current* through it.

Answer (score 0):

Since the problem does not state what the resistance of the wire across the marked resistor is, you can only assume ideal wires (zero resistance) and therefore the wire is a short circuit and no current flows through the marked resistor.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of the wire piece as being a resistor with zero resistance. Applying the usual parallel total resistance formula gives $$R_\text{tot} = \frac{R \cdot 0\ \Omega}{R + 0\ \Omega} = 0\ \Omega.$$
Thus, this entire wire-parallel-to-resistor segment has zero voltage drop, and the resistor that has voltage cannot therefore accommodate current flowing through it.